# Flutter - How to stretch Column inside Row to maximum available height?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need create this UI in my flutter app:

[image]

It is row for my list. This is my code:

```
return Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: photoUrl,
      imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
        height: 112,
        width: 90,
      ),
    ),
    const SizedBox(
      width: 14,
    ),
    Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(
          '${title}',
        ),
        
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: descriptionWidth,
            child: Text(
              '${shortDescription}',
              maxLines: 2,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        
        Text(
          '${footer}',
        ),
        
      ],
    )
  ],
);
```

I need the test block to occupy a height equal to the image. but when the text is all in the middle, it takes up a lot less height. this is an example of how my code works now:

[image]

how do I fix this? How to stretch Column inside Row to maximum available height?

I tried several options but then it breaks the display of multi-line text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While height is fixed, you can wrap `Column` with `SizedBox(height:112)` and to control textOverflow, wrap `SizedBox` with `Expanded`.

```dart
Expanded(
  child: SizedBox(
    height: 112,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
```

**Full method**

```dart
 return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          /// replace with image
          height: 112,
          width: 90,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 14,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 112,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  '${title}',
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: Text(
                    '${shortDescription}',
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  '${footer}',
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For Maximum Height You can use

```
Expanded(
child : --- your child widget 
)
```

or

```
Flexible(
child: -- your child widget 
)
```

---

A widget that expands a child of a Row, Column, or Flex so that the child fills the available space.

Using an Expanded widget makes a child of a Row, Column, or Flex expand to fill the available space along the main axis (e.g., horizontally for a Row or vertically for a Column). If multiple children are expanded, the available space is divided among them according to the flex factor.

An Expanded widget must be a descendant of a Row, Column, or Flex, and the path from the Expanded widget to its enclosing Row, Column, or Flex must contain only StatelessWidgets or StatefulWidgets (not other kinds of widgets, like RenderObjectWidgets).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to fixed the card height for better positioning of your  text with the card image and then expand your column to dynamically handle the multiline of text. ANd you don't need to use the align widget

try the below code

```
Container(
            height: 112, // here you fixed the container height
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                CachedNetworkImage(
                  imageUrl:
                      "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/26745548?v=4",
                  imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                    height: 112,
                    width: 90,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 14,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  // here expand your column
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'title',
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '{shortDescription 23487509387 2039487502930349857  03984 5 30498 503498 503948 70293847 50923487503}',
                       
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'footer',
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
```

output:

[image]